# How to print right digit 3 integers in shell script

Tags: shell-script

How to print last 3 digit of input variable in shell script
Ex: Input variable 236548 and Output should be 548

Comment: What if the input is more complicated, such as `ab123c` or `nodigits`?

Comment: It is Integers only strings not required

Comment: Please explain what the shell script should do in all these cases (by [editing your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/578243/edit)). Thanks!

Comment: Also please indicate which shell your script uses

Comment: it is one tool fetched the data from Node and print right 3 digit only,
So it fetched one data ex: 110012301 and  print should be 301
I want to write in shell script coding.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the number is stored in the variable `var`:

```
echo "${var#${var%???}}"
```

Here, `${var%???}` expands to the last three characters of `$var` *removed*, leaving whatever needs to be removed from the front of `$var`.  This result is used to remove those character from the start of `$var`.

In words: "Remove from the start whatever is left of `$var` after removing the last three characters of `$var`, and call `echo` with that".

Comment: I fetched the data from

lget Iub= rbsId > $rbsid

now $rbsid= 1170028601  (now stored)

again i fetched right 3 digit 601 only from $rbsid and store another variable

$rbsid1=  601

How to fetch this value from $rbsid variable

Comment: @DeepakAltia If you have clarifications to you question, please update your question.

Comment: Hi,

while putting command

"lget Iub= rbsId > $rbsid"   it fetched data from node and stored $rbsid = 1170028601

now i want to store last 3 digit from $rbsid variable in another variable,

Ex: $rbsid1 = 601

Comment: @DeepakAltia If you want to add more context to you question, please update your question. If you want to ask a new question, then please ask a new question. I don't know what you mean by your comment. The command that you show looks like nonsense to me.

Answer (score 1):

If your shell supports substring expansions with negative offsets like `bash`, `ksh`, `zsh`, you could do

```
$ var=236548
$ echo "${var: -3}"
548
```

echoing the last three characters of `var`.

Comment: I fetched the data from "lget Iub= rbsId > $rbsid"   now $rbsid= 1170028601 (now stored) again i fetched right 3 digit 601 only from $rbsid and store another variable EX: "$rbsid1= 601" How to fetch this value from $rbsid variable

Comment: Try `rbsid=1170028601; rbsid1=${rbsid: -3}; echo "$rbsid1"`

Comment: ERB-GE-9STPAUSE-01> $rbsid1 = ${rbsid: -3}

$rbsid1 = ${rbsid: -3}


ERB-GE-9STPAUSE-01> $rbsid1 = $rbsid: -3

$rbsid1 = 1170028601: -3

ERB-GE-9STPAUSE-01> $rbsid1 = {{$rbsid}: -3}

$rbsid1 = {{1170028601}: -3}

I have tried different procedures but output is different

Comment: Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/578243/edit) your question and tell us what shell you're using. From what I can see your assignments look wrong. Don't use the `$` on the left hand side of the variable assignment and don't use space characters before and after the `=`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `tail` command:

```
$> echo 236548 | tail -c 4
548
```

for a variable you would use $:

```
$> echo "$MYVAR" | tail -c 4
```

Comment: tail is not working, 

i want to store in a variable

lget Iub= rbsId > $rbsid
$rbsid = 1170028601

now i want to store in $rbsid1 = 28601

How to fetch this data

Comment: Variables inside single quotes are not expanded